# sort club based on club members in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app in which I have 2 tables... Clubs and clubmembers..

club has many clubmembers
and clubmember belongs to clubs...
I will provide screenshot of table columns

[image]

my clubmembers is referencing to clubs using club_id foreign key

I want to find out clubs based on maximum no of clubmembers...
I am using a query like this.. but this is not working.. can anyone help me in ordering clubs based on number of clubmembers ?

my current query

```
SELECT clubs.*, COUNT(club.id) AS total
FROM clubs
  INNER JOIN clubmembers ON clubs.id = clubmembers.id
  GROUP BY clubmembers.club_id
  ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Is this a one time curiosity, or an often used sorting method?  Do you have the ability to add a column?

Comment: yes I can add columns to any table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining on the wrong key:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(cm.id) AS total
FROM clubs c INNER JOIN
     clubmembers cm
     ON c.id = cm.club_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Notice that I also introduced table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: this is giving opposite number of members.. like club 1 has 3 members... query shows 2... and club 2 have 2 members and shows 3, I changes DESC to ASC and now it works... thanks... can u explain how my original query was wrong so that i can understand the problem I faced ?

Comment: This is the way that you could make the query in SQL without further updates to the database.  However, this request won't scale well in terms of performance.  If performance is not an issue (either because the DB is and will remain small, or the request is only being made manually, ...etc) this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Using rails `:counter_cache` option on the belongs to association.

[This blog](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/proper-counter-cache-migrations-in-rails/) shows how you can set one up quickly.

Long story short, you add a column to `clubs` named `members_count`. Then update the `members` model to have the following as their association line (including any other association modifiers you already have)

```
belongs_to :author, counter_cache: true
```

Then you will need to initialize the counts for your existing data by running `Club.reset_counters` if your data set is small enough, or following the guide listed in [the blog](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/proper-counter-cache-migrations-in-rails/) if the data set is large.

After this set up you will be able to simply add `.order(members_count: :desc)` to any rails query on club.  This eliminates the need for a joins request (by having the members update the count when they join/leave a club).  Which will increase the efficiency of the sort.

**NOTE**

This will only work if the data is only created/updated/destroyed via rails.  If any other system modifies the data or direct db edits are made, it wont fire the callbacks, and wont update the counter cache.